# checking substring of another string in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm currently trying to figure out how to check if "true" or "false" is a substring of whatever is passed in. I am using the type parser, as shown here:

`newtype Parser a = Parser (String -> Maybe (String,a))`

This is what I have so far:

```
import Data.text (replace, isInfixOf) 

parseBool :: Parser Bool
parseBool = Parser (\s -> 
  case s of 
    (isInfixOf "true", s) == True -> Just(replace "true" "" s, True)
    (isInfixOf "false", s) == True -> Just(replace "false" "" s, True)
    otherwise = Nothing)
```

Basically the parser passes in a string and we check the cases. If it is the case where "true" isInfixOf s is True then we return ...
If it is the case where "false" isInfixOf s is True then we return... otherwise return Nothing.
I have also used replace because it should be returning something that looks like this:

```
> parseBool "truehello"
> Just ("hello", True)
```

To add to this, there is also a case where if it is not just "true" or "false" on its own it will be Nothing:

```
> parseBool "ttruehello"
> Nothing
```

I think there may be something wrong with how I'm handing isInfixOf as there is an error that says

*parse error in pattern match*

However, I cannot figure out the issue or how to go about this.

Comment: If `ttruehello` should not match, then you probably don't want `isInfixOf`, but rather `isPrefixOf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a fundamental issue with how `case` statements work in Haskell.
The matched values should be of the variable itself.

For example:

```hs
case s of
  "hello" -> ...
  "true"  -> ...


case ("hello" `isInfixOf` s) of
  True    -> ...
  False   -> ...

take m ys    = case (m,ys) of
    (0,_)    ->  []
    (_,[])   ->  []
    (n,x:xs) ->  x : take (n-1) xs
```

In your case, you may want to use guards as such:

```hs
import Data.Text (replace, isInfixOf) 

parseBool :: Parser Bool
parseBool = Parser parseFn
  where
    parseFn s
      | "true" `isInfixOf` s   = Just (replace "true" "" s, True)
      | "false" `isInfixOf` s  = Just (replace "false" "" s, True)
      | otherwise              = Nothing
```

You can also get use an `if` — `else`-`if` — `else` statement

```hs
import Data.Text (replace, isInfixOf) 

parseBool :: Parser Bool
parseBool = Parser (\s ->
  if "true" `isInfixOf` s
    then Just (replace "true" "" s, True)
  else if "false" `isInfixOf` s
    then Just (replace "false" "" s) True)
  else Nothing)
```

I think guards are better but that's up to you — they effectively do the same thing.

Comment: that was such a good explanation, thank you so much!